# I cant understand why Octave (Matlab) presented this graph

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to make a fractal tree and Octave presents this graph:

[image]

However, I think my code does not have any mistakes.

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot_binary
function FractalTree()
totalIter=9;
angle=pi/6;
len1=3*1.2^tatalIter;
w=totalIter;
figure(1); clf
plot([0 0],[-len1,0],'LineWidth',w,'Color',[0 0 0]
hold on
drawBranches(pi/2,[0,0],totalIter-1, ...
    angle,totalIter);
    function drawBranches(initAngle,pt,Iter,... 
            angle, totalIter)
        len=1.2^Iter;
        x1=pt(1);
        y1=pt(2);
        ang1=initAngle+angle;
        ang2=initAngle-angle;
        x2=len*cos(ang1)+x1;
        y2=len*sin(ang1)+y1;
        x3=len*cos(ang2)+x1;
        y3=len*sin(ang2)+y1;
        w=Iter;
        c2=[1-Iter/totalIter 0 1-Iter/totalIter];
        p1=plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],'LineWidth',w,'Color',c2);
        p2=plot([x1,x3],[y1,y3],'LineWidth',w,'Color',c2);
        pause(0.01)
        if Iter-1>0
            drawBranches(ang1,[x2,y2],Iter-1,angle,... 
                totalIter);
            drawBranches(ang2,[x3,y3],Iter-1,angle,... 
                totalIter);
        end
   end
axis image
axis on
grid on
end
```

Comment: It's hard to understand from your post what you want. What is this fractal tree? What do you expect to get? Is your code based on someone else's algorithm / equation with example output?

Comment: Aside from my answer, that clearly shows that the code should work (after correcting some typos), the `graphic_toolkit` and `gnuplot_binary` are functions and should be called as such, i.e. `graphic_toolkit()` , `gnuplot_binary()`. You can see [this](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Introduction-to-Plotting.html) and [this](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Customizing-Toolkit-Behavior.html) to have an idea how to use these. In case of `gnuplot_binary()`, i don't think you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I put your code into the MATLAB Online R2020a, it gives me error. I deleted the first line, changed typo on line 5 from `len1=3*1.2^tatalIter;` to `len1=3*1.2^totalIter;` and added missing bracket on line 8 from `plot([0 0],[-len1,0],'LineWidth',w,'Color',[0 0 0]` to `plot([0 0],[-len1,0],'LineWidth',w,'Color',[0 0 0])`, so the code looks like this:

```
function FractalTree()
totalIter=9;
angle=pi/6;
len1=3*1.2^totalIter;
w=totalIter;
figure(1); clf
plot([0 0],[-len1,0],'LineWidth',w,'Color',[0 0 0])
hold on
drawBranches(pi/2,[0,0],totalIter-1, ...
    angle,totalIter);
    function drawBranches(initAngle,pt,Iter,... 
            angle, totalIter)
        len=1.2^Iter;
        x1=pt(1);
        y1=pt(2);
        ang1=initAngle+angle;
        ang2=initAngle-angle;
        x2=len*cos(ang1)+x1;
        y2=len*sin(ang1)+y1;
        x3=len*cos(ang2)+x1;
        y3=len*sin(ang2)+y1;
        w=Iter;
        c2=[1-Iter/totalIter 0 1-Iter/totalIter];
        p1=plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],'LineWidth',w,'Color',c2);
        p2=plot([x1,x3],[y1,y3],'LineWidth',w,'Color',c2);
        pause(0.01)
        if Iter-1>0
            drawBranches(ang1,[x2,y2],Iter-1,angle,... 
                totalIter);
            drawBranches(ang2,[x3,y3],Iter-1,angle,... 
                totalIter);
        end
   end
axis image
axis on
grid on
end
```

And it gives me the following image

[image: Nice figure of a fractal tree.]

Comment: It also seems to work here: https://octave-online.net/, although the generator tells me that it ran out of time to generate it and got stuck somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I can confirm that the above code also works on a normal octave v5.2.0 installation with no modifications.